# Automatically update a filter

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a graph depicting 3 years of data, and an option to pick which year(s) of data they want to see.  I'm pulling the data from a chart that I have put in formulas that change the data to #N/A if they choose to unselect that year.  But the graph still shows that year, is there a way to get the graph to recoginze the NA options as something that should not be graphed?

my data looks something like this:

Period  # orders    #shipments
P6/2014;     281    74
P7/2014;    498 126
P8/2014;    589 132
P9/2014;    655 158
P10/2014;   679 161
P11/2014;   489 115
P12/2014;   574 129
P13/2014;   340 80
P1/2015;    615 225
P2/2015;    0   0
P3/2015;    0   0
P4/2015;    0   0
P5/2015;    0   0
P6/2015;    0   0
P7/2015;    0   0
P8/2015;    0   0
P9/2015;    0   0
P10/2015;   0   0
P11/2015;   0   0
P12/2015;   0   0
P13/2015;   0   0

and switches to this when 2015 is unselected:

Period  # orders    #shipments
P6/2014;    281 74
P7/2014;    498 126
P8/2014;    589 132
P9/2014;    655 158
P10/2014;   679 161
P11/2014;   489 115
P12/2014;   574 129
P13/2014;   340 80
P1/2015;    #N/A    #N/A
P2/2015;    #N/A    #N/A
P3/2015;    #N/A    #N/A
P4/2015;    #N/A    #N/A
P5/2015;    #N/A    #N/A
P6/2015;    #N/A    #N/A
P7/2015;    #N/A    #N/A
P8/2015;    #N/A    #N/A
P9/2015;    #N/A    #N/A
P10/2015;   #N/A    #N/A
P11/2015;   #N/A    #N/A
P12/2015;   #N/A    #N/A
P13/2015;   #N/A    #N/A

the formula I have in those areas to do that change is;  =IF($AY$13=TRUE,$J24,NA())

So I was hoping that the Graph I have selected on all this data would see that there is no data in any of the 2015 data and just not include it in the chart.

Comment: try changing the formula from `IF(conditions,"#N/A")` to `IF(conditions, #N/A)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to presume that you have a chart whose source data has all the years and either the value for that year or #N/A - hopefully created using the `NA()` function. 
In that case, the years are still showing up on your chart because they're still in your data. You need to change it around so the years in the source data are removed entirely. 
You can do this with a pivot chart although you'll need to write a little VBA to refresh the Pivot Cache when the user selects different years. 
You can also do this with some formulas and dynamic ranges. The feasibility of that depends on how large and dynamic your chart data is. If you're showing a summary for each year, it could be easy. If you're showing hundreds of data points, it could be cumbersome. 
Can you add an example of what your desired result is so we can craft an answer? (I'll update this answer based on your response.)

---

**UPDATE BASED ON OP'S UPDATE**
Excel isn't dropping the `NA()` values because it can still see them even though there's nothing to graph. It's the same as having text there. Your axis still sees all the periods so it has labels to put on an axis and then just skips the data it can't handle. We have to change it so that Excel only looks at the data we want.

- Problem 1) Not charting certain years
- Problem 2) Still charting what comes *after* those years. (E.G. chart 2014 & 2016 only)

If it was just Problem 1, we could set up a few [dynamic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287) [named](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html) [ranges](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm) and set them as the chart source. However, because of Problem 2, we have to setup an interim table first and *then* create the named ranges.
First, I apologize if this gets a little dense. I am often accused of being too verbose. I *really* wish I could just upload a file on here...

### STEP 1

Here's the CSV version of my starting point. My data is in the range `A1:D35` (Notice that I added a column in the front called `Order` - it'll help later - and expanded the data into 2016.)

> Order,Period,Orders,Shipments
>  1,P6/2014,281,74
>   2,P7/2014,498,126
>  3,P8/2014,589,132
>  4,P9/2014,655,158
>   5,P10/2014,679,161
>  6,P11/2014,489,115
>  7,P12/2014,574,129
>   8,P13/2014,340,80
>  9,P1/2015,615,225
>  10,P2/2015,0,0
>   11,P3/2015,0,0
>  12,P4/2015,0,0
>  13,P5/2015,0,0
>   14,P6/2015,0,0
>  15,P7/2015,0,0
>  16,P8/2015,0,0
>   17,P9/2015,0,0
>  18,P10/2015,0,0
>  19,P11/2015,0,0
>   20,P12/2015,0,0
>  21,P13/2015,0,0
>  22,P1/2016,0,0
>   23,P2/2016,0,0
>  24,P3/2016,0,0
>  25,P4/2016,0,0
>   26,P5/2016,0,0
>  27,P6/2016,0,0
>  28,P7/2016,0,0
>   29,P8/2016,0,0
>  30,P9/2016,0,0
>  31,P10/2016,0,0
>   32,P11/2016,0,0
>  33,P12/2016,0,0
>  34,P13/2016,0,0

### STEP 2

Add the interim table to `NA()` what isn't needed. For you, this might be the same as Step 1. For me, I used Step 1 as my raw data so I need this other step. My data is in the range `F1:I35`. It ended up looking like this CSV when I chose to drop 2015.

> Order,Period,Orders,Shipments
>  1,P6/2014,281,74
>   2,P7/2014,498,126
>  3,P8/2014,589,132
>  4,P9/2014,655,158
>   5,P10/2014,679,161
>  6,P11/2014,489,115
>  7,P12/2014,574,129
>   8,P13/2014,340,80
>  9,P1/2015,#N/A,#N/A
>  10,P2/2015,#N/A,#N/A
>   11,P3/2015,#N/A,#N/A
>  12,P4/2015,#N/A,#N/A
>   13,P5/2015,#N/A,#N/A
>  14,P6/2015,#N/A,#N/A
>   15,P7/2015,#N/A,#N/A
>  16,P8/2015,#N/A,#N/A
>   17,P9/2015,#N/A,#N/A
>  18,P10/2015,#N/A,#N/A
>   19,P11/2015,#N/A,#N/A
>  20,P12/2015,#N/A,#N/A
>   21,P13/2015,#N/A,#N/A
>  22,P1/2016,0,0
>  23,P2/2016,0,0
>   24,P3/2016,0,0
>  25,P4/2016,0,0
>  26,P5/2016,0,0
>   27,P6/2016,0,0
>  28,P7/2016,0,0
>  29,P8/2016,0,0
>   30,P9/2016,0,0
>  31,P10/2016,0,0
>  32,P11/2016,0,0
>   33,P12/2016,0,0
>  34,P13/2016,0,0

### STEP 3

Add a third table that extracts just the values that aren't `#N/A` in the second table. This is accomplished using array formulas. Remember how we added the `Order` column? We're going to find all those values that don't line up with `#N/A` in the `Orders` Column and then use what's left to pull in the rest of the data. My third table is in the range `K1:N35`.
The formula for the first value in the `Order` column is: (For all these formulas, it is important to enter this with `SHIFT+ENTER` to turn them into array formulas as indicated by the `{  }` brackets on either end.)

```
{=MIN(IF(NOT(ISERROR($H$2:$H$35)),$F$2:$F$35))}
```

This finds the first value in the `Order` column of the second table (`F2:F35`) where the `Orders` column (`H2:H35`) is not an error.
The formula for the rest of the second value in the `Order` column is:

```
=IF(OR($K2=0,$K2=MAX($F$2:$F$35)),0,MIN(IF(NOT(ISERROR($H$2:$H$35)),IF($F$2:$F$35>$K2,$F$2:$F$35))))
```

This first checks if the previous value (`K2` in this case) is `0` or the max of the values from the 2nd table - which means we're done - and returns `0` in that case. Otherwise, it find the first value in the `Order` column of the second table that is larger than the previous value found and where the `Orders` column is not an error.
This formula can be dragged down to the rest of the column. The result looks like this CSV.

> Order
>  1
>  2
>  3
>  4
>  5
>  6
>  7
>  8
>  22
>   23
>  24
>  25
>  26
>  27
>  28
>  29
>  30
>  31
>  32
>   33
>  34
>  0
>  0
>  0
>  0
>  0
>  0
>  0
>  0
>  0
>   0
>  0
>  0
>  0

### STEP 4

Use a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` to lookup the values for whatever `Order` values survived Step 3. The formula Period, Orders, and Shipments are given in order as:

```
=INDEX(B$2:B$35,MATCH($K2,$A$2:$A$35,0))
=INDEX(C$2:C$35,MATCH($K2,$A$2:$A$35,0))
=INDEX(D$2:D$35,MATCH($K2,$A$2:$A$35,0))
```

Input them as the first record and copy/paste or drag them down for the rest. Note that these refer back to the first table and the only difference is the first parameter. Here's the CSV for what it looks like when you choose to hide 2015.

> Order,Period,Orders,Shipments
>  1,P6/2014,281,74
>   2,P7/2014,498,126
>  3,P8/2014,589,132
>  4,P9/2014,655,158
>   5,P10/2014,679,161
>  6,P11/2014,489,115
>  7,P12/2014,574,129
>   8,P13/2014,340,80
>  22,P1/2016,0,0
>  23,P2/2016,0,0
>   24,P3/2016,0,0
>  25,P4/2016,0,0
>  26,P5/2016,0,0
>   27,P6/2016,0,0
>  28,P7/2016,0,0
>  29,P8/2016,0,0
>   30,P9/2016,0,0
>  31,P10/2016,0,0
>  32,P11/2016,0,0
>   33,P12/2016,0,0
>  34,P13/2016,0,0
>  0,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A
>   0,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A
>  0,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A
>  0,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A
>   0,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A
>  0,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A
>  0,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A
>   0,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A
>  0,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A
>  0,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A
>   0,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A
>  0,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A
>  0,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A

### STEP 5

Create a dynamic named range for X-Axis labels, Series 1, and Series 2. I'm using Excel 2010 and it doesn't allow you to set the whole chart data source at once if it's a dynamic named range; it keeps reverting back to a hard-coded range that doesn't update. That means we have to create one for each series and the axis individually. To create a named range, go to the `Formulas` ribbon and click on `Name Manager` somewhere near the middle. In the dialog window, click the `New` button at the top left. Give it a name and a range to refer to. The trick here is that certain functions like `OFFSET` return range objects so you can use those here instead of something like `=A1:D35`. Here are the 3 named ranges I made and their formula.
Name: `rngPeriod`
Formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$L$2,0,0,IFERROR(MATCH(0,Sheet1!$K:$K,0)-2,MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A),Sheet1!$K:$K,0)-1))
```

Name: `rngOrders`
Formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$M$2,0,0,IFERROR(MATCH(0,Sheet1!$K:$K,0)-2,MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A),Sheet1!$K:$K,0)-1))
```

Name: `rngShipments`
Formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$N$2,0,0,IFERROR(MATCH(0,Sheet1!$K:$K,0)-2,MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$A:$A),Sheet1!$K:$K,0)-1))
```

Each formula works in the same way. Start at the top of the data we want. Go down one. Find the first `0` in the `Order` column or find the max value - which indicates the end of the data we want - and make the range tall enough to cover everything from the first row to the last row we want. *Key Point: This will cause an error and your graph won't show if you choose to hide every year so every value is `#N/A` and the very first value in the `Order` table is `0` because then the `MATCH` function returns `1` and `1-2=-1` and you can't have a range that's `-1` rows tall.*

### STEP 6

Setup your chart to use these dynamic named ranges. Use whatever value you want for `Series name:` but `Series values:` should be the names of the dynamic ranges. The - very annoying - key point here is that you have to include the file name. Do the same thing for the Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels and you'll be all set. My chart ending up using these for Series 1, Series 2, and Axis Label:

```
=sample.xlsx!rngOrders
=sample.xlsx!rngShipments
=sample.xlsx!rngPeriod
```

Comment: I updated with, what I hope, is a good enough example

Comment: I've added a solution that uses dynamic named ranges. It could probably be a neater finished product using the PivotTable + VBA solution but PivotCharts are messy in their own right.